# How to return to Root Element in QDomDocument ?

Tags: xml, qt, xml-parsing

I am currently working on QDomDocument and I want to implement several functions but I want to use just one QDomDocument. So to do that while working I need to return to Root value sometimes. 
For example I have an XML like this ;

```
<Root>
  <Node A>
    <Node B>
    <\Node B>
   <\Node A>
 <Root>
```

And think that I am working on Node B, but what should I do to return  ?

Can you please tell me how I can back to root value using QDomDocument ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy. `documentElement()` returns the root element.

```
QDomElement QDomDocument::documentElement () const

Returns the root element of the document.
```